# Selecting all 12 month datetimes for a given year

Tags: c#, linq

I'm selecting an `IEnumerable` of `DateTime` by using a list of `int` which represent a year.

Each of the resulting `DateTime`s is given a default month and day of `1` so e.g.

```
List<int> years = new List<int>() { 2018, 2017, 2016 };
var dateTimes = years.Select(x => new DateTime(int.Parse(x), 1, 1));
```

Gives me `2018/01/01`, `2017/01/01`, `2016/01/01` (ignoring the time component)

I want to get the same results but for each *month* of each year too, so actually 36 results for three given years:

```
2018/01/01
2018/02/01
... 
2018/11/01
2018/12/01
2017/01/01
...
2016/12/01
```

(this is using non-US culture datetime where months are the middle value)

I was wondering if C# had a really nice shortcut like the range notation

```
var dateTimes = years.Select(x => new DateTime(int.Parse(x), 1..12, 1));
```

But that certainly doesn't work.

Any syntactic-shortcut way to achieve this without just looping `i = 1 to 12` style?

The best I came up with was:

```
var dateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
foreach(var y in years)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) dateTimes.Add(new DateTime(int.Parse(y), i, 1));
}
```

Which does exactly what I want but though there was a more succinct way to write.

Comment: Only way is more LINQ: `var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);` -> `from year in years from month in months select new DateTime(year, month, 1);`

Comment: Thanks, that's a decent way - there's probably not a good chain syntax way of writing that?

Comment: I cannot say it's easier to read, but... `years.SelectMany(year => months.Select(month => (year, month))).Select(x => new DateTime(x.year, x.month, 1));` -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/zDOs8n

Comment: Actually the way it's set out in the lines I do find it easier to read! Wordy LINQ just confuses me, no symbols to break up the `from object in objects select object2 in out select up out down all around`

Comment: You are a programmer, write an extension method and move on

Comment: if you really want the range syntax https://dotnetfiddle.net/fY9bc5 as an example, though you will need to zero base it :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  var dateTimes = years.SelectMany(y => Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(m => new DateTime(y, m, 1))); // .ToList() if you want
```

`Enumerable.Range()` available from .NET 3.5

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` was introduced in .NET 3.5, in 2008... long, long before .NET 5.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Obliged.  Post updated.